# Utilising methods on a list object

Tags: python, list, object, methods, javascript-objects

I've had a gander and haven't found a satisfactory answer. In JavaScript it's possible to simply add a method to an array alla:

```
const makeGrid = (size) => {
 let grid = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  let row = new Array(size).fill(0);
  grid.push(row);
 }

 grid.toggleChunkPlaced = (x, y) => {
  grid[y][x] === 0 ? (grid[y][x] = 1) : (grid[y][x] = 0);
 };
return grid
};
```

However I'm not sure if it is possible (or recommended) to do in Python - my best guess is something like:

```
def make_grid(size):
 grid = []
 for i in size:
    row = [0]*size
    grid.append(row)

 grid.toggle_chunk_placed = lambda x, y: grid[y][x] = 1 if grid[y][x] == 0 else grid[y][x] = 0
 return grid
```

Comment: `push` is `append`. Also, you shouldn't stick in extra attributes to objects like that. For a `list` it's not possible, for custom objects it is but you shouldn't do it. Just define a normal function that takes the `grid` as an argument.

Comment: Also, snake_case instead of camelCase.

Comment: Perhaps if you can show us where/how `toggleChunkPlaced` is getting called, we could have a bit more insight as to how you'd want to do it in python.

Comment: append and camel case changed (thanks - js creeping in there) the functionality isn't particularly important I simply call the method on an instance of the grid in another function passing in the coordinates of the chunk to toggle. I'm more interested in whether it is actually possible to do in python or not. Cheers

Comment: Nope. You can't do that with a `list`. It is possible if you really badly want it to be possible but I don't think that's the case. If you do want it, I'll have to write an answer that would probably only get downvotes . What I mean is, there is a better way.

Comment: Normally you'd want to have a function `toggle_chunk_placed(grid, x, y)` that does the job. And just call it like it's defined instead of `grid.toggle_chunk_placed(x, y)`

Comment: You also can't do full-on statements inside that single line if-else. So you want to write `grid[y][x] = 1 if grid[y][x] == 0 else 0`. And then you can just use the fact that bools are ints and just write `grid[y][x] = int(grid[y][x] == 0)`

Comment: Ah brilliant thanks for your answers - exactly what I wanted to know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Nope. You can't do that with a list. It is possible if you really badly want it to be possible but I don't think that's the case. If you do want it, I'll have to write an answer that would probably only get downvotes . What I mean is, there is a better way. – [Diptangsu Goswami](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67938250/utilising-methods-on-a-list-object-in-python-js-dev-learning-python/67938733#comment120081811_67938250)